# Gmail: shortcut to filter messages like this

Tags: javascript, gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to quickly access my Gmail emails sent by the same sender. That will save me some time and fluidify my workflow.

I'm dreaming of a shortcut to find those emails quickly and, unless I'm mistaken, there is unfortunately not such a default shortcut in Gmail.

Did anyone try to do the same, and if yes, how did you do it?

I'm trying to use [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck/reviews?hl=en-US&gl=US) Google Chrome extension by firing a JavaScript event, but for now I couldn't make it work:

[image: Firing a JavaScript event with Shortkeys]

All help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

i think it can help you:

[image]

```js
var main = document.querySelector('div[role=main]');
var el = main.querySelector('span[email]');
var senderEmail = el.getAttribute('email');
var querySearch = 'from:(' + senderEmail + ')';
var queryUrl = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/' + querySearch;
window.location.href = queryUrl;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Filter messages like this does more than just from: (). What we (or at least I) really want is to be able to click on the button option more easily.

Comment: 90% of the time I use the "Filter messages like this" option, it gives me a filter based mainly on the sender, so this should be a good starting point.

Comment: I just had to change the Activation Settings from "All sites except" to "Only on Specific Sites", and add "\*mail.google.com\*" (with wildcards). This answer is a good one.